# How can i add NewLine Break in string Join?

Tags: c#

I have the following code, how can I add New line Break?

```
public override string ToString()
{
    var values = new[] { AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, $"{State} {PostalCode}", Country };
    return string.Join(", ", values.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)));
}
```

I would like to get something similar to this

```
 AddressLine1
 AddressLine2
 City, State, PostalCode
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use newline as a separator like:

```
return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    values.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)));
```

By using `Environment.NewLine`, you ensure the correct character sequence is used based on the platform your code currently runs on (e.g. `\r\n` on Windows or `\n` on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

[Environment.NewLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=netcore-3.1)

```
string.Join(Environment.NewLine, values.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)));
```